# sql query to show data from price between two columns C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

EDIT: I am not able to format my code below, if any one can fix it.

I am new to sql queries and still learning.

Table Name: CommissionSetupTable.

I want to display @Paisa if gross_amount is between the range of @FromRate and @ToRate

[image]

Below is my code:

```
    string paisa;
        private void load_commission_setup()
        {
            SqlCeConnection conn = null;
            SqlCeCommand cmd = null;
            SqlCeDataReader rdr = null;

        try
        {
            conn =
                new SqlCeConnection(
                   @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.sdf;Persist Security Info=False");
            conn.Open();

            int rowindex = purchaseBillTableDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1;
            gross_amount = double.Parse(purchaseBillTableDataGridView[10, rowindex].Value.ToString());

            // Gross Amount is between the ranges of FromRate and ToRate.


            cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT Paisa FROM CommissionSetupTable WHERE='" + gross_amount.ToString() + "' BETWEEN @FromRate AND @ToRate;", conn);
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (rdr == null)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    paisa = rdr["Paisa"].ToString();

                }
                rdr.Close();
                cmd.Dispose();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            int rowindex = purchaseBillTableDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1;
            purchaseBillTableDataGridView[11, rowindex].Value = paisa;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hope that you forgot to give values for the placeholders `@FromRate AND @ToRate`

Comment: values will be taken from FromRate and ToRate columns in CommissionSetupTable.

Comment: then this question is not (minimal complete veriable example)[http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve]. Hint post the relevent table structure.

Comment: What are you getting ? It seems to be ok

Comment: @SaadSuri its not working...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And where are you passing your parameter values ?

Comment: these values are in a separate table, it has data in it. 
From Rate: 0  and ToRate: 9.99,  Paisa 0.07.

if the gross amount is between these ranges it will get paisa 0.07

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax to use here is the following

```
  cmd = new SqlCeCommand(@"SELECT Paisa FROM CommissionSetupTable 
        WHERE @gross BETWEEN FromRate AND ToRate;", conn);
```

Notice that the two field names should not be prefixed with @, otherwise they will be considered parameters placeholders.

And now, before executing the command, add the parameter for the @gross placeholder

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@gross", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = gross_amount;
```

I don't know what is the exact datatype of the columns FromRate and EndRate, but 
note that you should use the correct datatype for your parameter. Do not pass a string and expect the database engine do the conversion for you. (or worse concatenate your value to the rest of the sql using ToString()). This is always wrong also if sometime the database engine could understand your values.

**EDIT**
Also, following your comments below, it appears that this line is wrong

```
int rowindex = purchaseBillTableDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1;
```

If your DataGridView has the property AllowUserToAddRow set to True then you want to use

```
int rowindex = purchaseBillTableDataGridView.Rows.Count - 2;
```

because the first line points to the empty row added to the DataGridView for inserting a new record.

Comment: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`
getting this error. 

I'm getting gross amount from here
`int rowindex = purchaseBillTableDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1;
                gross_amount = double.Parse(purchaseBillTableDataGridView[10, rowindex].Value.ToString());`

Comment: error on this `cmd.Parameters.Add("@gross", DbType.Decimal).Value = gross_amount;`

Comment: It is SqlDbType, but on which line did you get the exception?

Comment: the line i posted above cmd parameters add

Comment: That's weird. The line goes immediately after the first one so it is acting on an initialized SqlCeCommand. I can't see how this could trigger a Null Reference Exception.

Comment: `string quantity;
string rate;

                if (purchaseBillTableDataGridView[10, rowindex].Selected == true)
                {
                    gross_amount = double.Parse(quantity) * double.Parse(rate);
                    purchaseBillTableDataGridView[10, rowindex].Value = gross_amount;
                 
                }`

Comment: I see it now. The problem is caused by the property AllowUserToAddRow set to true. This means that the DataGridView has an empty row at the bottom where you can add a new record. But this means also that your rowindex variable points to this row that doesn't contain any value. Trying to work with that row brings up the exception. I suppose that you want the last filled row, so the value for rowindex should be Rows.Count - 2.

Comment: i am not getting any error now by forcing not to take empty values from index, but it is still not showing commission price. [NO ERROR] but value not showing up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129976/discussion-between-patrick-and-steve).

Comment: Try to use `WHERE @gross >= FromRate AND @gross <= ToRate` instead of BETWEEN (or also remove the WHERE condition interely just to check if your code reaches the following while loop with something to work with). In any case, at this point, using a debugger will help a lot to understand what's going on

Comment: allow user to set row is false.